How to fix "Engine 'gini' loading failed" warning
I ran a simple Python program that uses xarray, I'm running via Spyder (installed as part of Anaconda). And, although it did not result in an error, I encountered this RuntimeWarning:
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\plugins.py:110: RuntimeWarning: Engine 'gini' loading failed:
DLL load failed while importing _network: The specified module could not be found.
  external_backend_entrypoints = backends_dict_from_pkg(entrypoints_unique)

I was trying to make updates or installations, but I can't find "gini" in the list of modules or libraries in the anaconda.org website. I'm currently using Spyder 6 with Python v.3.11.10 and my xarray is v.2024.10.0. What is the cause of this warning, and how can I get rid of this?
